# Wordpress upload fail - internal server error

Tags: wordpress, lamp, internal-server-error

Uploading files via the wordpress uploader (flash or html) mysteriously fails now. It worked up to yesterday, now it throws. Error_log doesn't show anything related to that.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domain.com and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Can someone help me trace back the problem? I'm on a brand new dedicated server running on CentOS 5.7 2G RAM.

php memory_limit = 128M

Let me know if you need any other information, i'll do my best to answer them... So you can help me answer mine °-)

**UPDATE**

I found this in the global server error log:

```
mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 132480 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)
```

Comment: The error log *will* show something related to it - a full explanation of what went wrong will be *somewhere*

Comment: indeed, after some more search,  i checked the main server error log, which returns `mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 132480 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)`

Answer (score 1):

Your fcgi settings use the default value of `MaxRequestLen` (131072)

Open apache vhost file and set the value for example to 4MB, aka `FcgidMaxRequestLen` 4000000.